# How do I express a Boolean function with don't cares (X) inputs?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I know how to minimize a Boolean function with X as outputs (using K-map).

I have encountered an exercise in which I am asked to write the Normal Disjunctive Canonical Form (NDCF)/ Sum of Products (SoP) but i have X as inputs.

Does it mean I will not take them into consideration when writing the minterms for where the functions has output high (1)?

For example:

```
A B C | Y
0 X 0 | 1
0 X 1 | 0
1 0 0 | 1
1 0 1 | 0
1 1 0 | 0
1 1 1 | 1

Will Y = A'C' + AB'C' + ABC ?
```

Also can this be done directly from the truth table, no need for a K-map unless we have to minimize?

Comment: You can use Boolean logic for distribution with A(XOR{B,C}) but may not help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `x` means the input is ignored. Technically it's not really ignored

```
A B C | Y
0 X 0 | 1
```

could be expanded to

```
A B C | Y
0 0 0 | 1
0 1 0 | 1
```

Comment: @Mr.Hondo  Should you choose to expand it, you would (typically) not include that term in your final Boolean expression as it makes no contribution.   In this case, `!A||!C` is same as `!A!B!C || !AB!C`  i.e. optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since X is a don't care condition, it can be used to simplify the expression.

You state:

> Will \$Y = \bar A \bar C + A \bar B \bar C + ABC\$ ?

\$Y = \bar A \bar C (1 + \bar B) + A \bar B \bar C + ABC\$

\$Y = \bar A \bar C + \bar A \bar B \bar C + A \bar B \bar C + ABC\$

\$Y = \bar A \bar C + \bar B \bar C (\bar A + A) + ABC\$

The minimal expression is \$Y = \bar A \bar C + \bar B \bar C + ABC\$